# Error in data[1:1000, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I'm beginner in R. I'm trying to subset a data and add it to another variable,Here is my code till now:

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(cluster)
library(clusterCrit)
library(TSrepr)
library(OpenML)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(animation)
library(gganimate)
library(av)
data <- OpenML::getOMLDataSet(data.id = 41060)
data <- data.matrix(data$data)
data_cons <- data[1:1000,]
period <- 48
```

, but I receive the following error:

```
Error in data[1:1000, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I appreciate it if anyone guid me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run `install.packages('farff')` first.

For me your code works, no error:

```r
library(OpenML)

data <- OpenML::getOMLDataSet(data.id = 41060)
data <- data.matrix(data$data)
data_cons <- data[1:1000,]
```